# Proving that a polynomial has two real roots.

Tags: calculus

For example, to prove that the function $x^8+x-1=0$ has exactly two roots, we first prove that $f$ has at most $2$ real roots by using differentiation. $f'(x)=8x^7+1=0$, by using that the function has two roots and therefore it should have at least one point such that $f '(c)=0$ and then we use IVT to prove that it has exactly two roots. First of all, Are these correct? If yes, when I'm given a function such as $5x^4-9x^2-1=g(x)$ to prove that it has exactly $2$ roots, because its derivative has $3$ roots, I cannot first prove that it has at most $2$ roots and cannot solve it.

So as you see, my question is how we can prove that $5x^4-9x^2-1=0$ has exactly two roots.

Comment: $g(x)=h(x^2)$ where $h(x)=5x^2-9x-1$. Note that $h(x)=0$  has two solutions, only one of them non-negative. The argument for $x^8+x-1$ is OK.

Comment: Okay, but what should I do if I am given x^4-6x^2-8x+1=0, its derivative has 2 roots but still I should try to prove that it has exactly two roots.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! If you look at the [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3466098/edit). You can see how the mathematical type was made using \$ signs. Can you make sure to do this when you ask questions here: it makes it a little easier on the eyes.

Comment: Well, the problem of counting real roots can be solved algorithmically using [Sturm's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem). It is not the most efficient, but at least it is short to explain and read.

Comment: You can also weed out many problems with little work if you can apply [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), which for example applied to $x^8+x-1$ tells you that it has exactly one positive root, and changing $x$ to $-x$ and applying it to $x^8-x-1$ tells it has exactly one negative root.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

It's purely algebraic, and uses only tools from high school:

This is a biquadratic equation, so set $t=x^2$. It is a nonnegative root of the quadratic equation:
$$5t^2-9t-1=0.$$
Now this quadratic has a positive discriminant, so it has two roots.  However, as the leading coefficient and the constant term have opposite signs, [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) imply that root is positive and the other is negative.

Can you conclude now?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=5x^4-9x^2-1$,$f'(x)=20x^3-18x$ has three roots from which two of them are opposite.This means critical numbers are 0 and $\sqrt{.9}$ and$-\sqrt{.9}$ This means the graph of the function has two minimm and a max at $x=0$. since $f(c)<0$
"c is a none zero  critical number", the result follows.