# Proving that a polynomial equation has two real roots, when its derivative has two roots.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, roots

For example, to prove that the function $x^8+x−1=0$ has exactly two roots, we first prove that $f$ has at most $2$ real roots by using differentiation. $f′(x)=8x^7+1=0$, by using that the function has two roots and therefore it should have at least one point such that $f'(c)=0$ and then we use IVT to prove that it has exactly two roots.

However, the equation $x^4−6x^2−8x+1=0$, its derivative has $2$ roots but still, I should try to prove that it has exactly two roots. If its derivative had one solution, then I could first prove that it has two roots at most as I did, so how should we approach the problem?

Comment: Why are you asking the [same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3466098/proving-that-a-polynomial-has-two-real-roots) question again?

Comment: Its second part is different if you look at carefully.

Comment: $x^4-6x^2-8x+1$ has $2$ changes of sign in its sequence of coefficients. Therefore, it has either $2$ or $0$ positive real roots, by Descartes rule of signs. Its translation $(x+1)^4-6(x+1)^2-8(x+1)+1=x^4+4x^3-16x-12$ has $1$ change of signs. Therefore, it has exactly $1$ positive real root. Hence the original polynomial had exactly $2$ positive real roots. It has $gcd$ equal to $1$ with its derivative. So all its roots are simple. Therefore, to have $4$ real roots, its derivative would have $3$ real roots.

Comment: Can we solve it by using just rolle's theorem and intermediate value theorem, because we will not be allowed to use such theorems.

Comment: You can replace the proof of the existence of two positive real roots using Descartes's rule by using the intermediate value theorem evaluating at conveniently chosen positive values of $x$. In the last part, that last sentence is Rolle's theorem. The fact that multiple roots are roots of both the polynomial and its derivative is a simple exercise that you could prove if your class doesn't assume it known.